# JSON to DataSet using Json.NET

Tags: json, dataset, json.net

hoping someone can lend a hand... I am trying to convert JSON to a DataSet, using the below example, but am having problems. I've validated that the JSON is correct, used a method as suggested by Kent. Thanks for your time and help!

**The following is my JSON:**

```
{"jsonData":[{"item1":"one"},{"item2":"two"}]}
```

**Here's my webservice C# code:**

```
[WebMethod]
        public string setWorkOrdersUpdated(object jsonData)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                xd = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonData.ToString());
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xd));
                return "success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "ERROR: " + e + "!";
            }
        }
```

Here's one of my error outputs:
d: "ERROR: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0..."

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? since I was getting a different error (Json.net 4.5). I have done the following and the exception has gone (basically passing the root element name).

**Edit: Added the complete code**

```
string jsonData = "{\"jsonData\":[{\"item1\":\"one\"},{\"item2\":\"two\"}]}";
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
//xd = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonData.ToString()); //Throws exception "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."
xd = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonData.ToString(), "jsonData");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xd));
```

Please let me know if this is not solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks keyr... I've tried your suggestion, but unfortunately I receive the same error, which points exactly to the line with the DeserializeXmlNode code. I'm using Json.Net 3.5 version 4.5

Comment: I think the problem has been fixed in the Json.net 4.5 version with my changes. Hope moving to 4.5 is not a constraint for you.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest Json.Net dll (version 4.5 release 11), using it with .Net 4.0... but still getting the same error. (here is the string that I pass in: `{"jsonData":[{"col1":"result1","col2":"result1"},{"col1":"result2","col2":"result2"}]}` How was your Json string formatted when you passed in for de-serialization?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question too... now it seems that there may be a problem how my JSON is passed/read by the c# webservice: {"Message":"Type \u0027System.String\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)\r\n at ..............

Comment: also, if I test only your code on the webservice (eg. I don't pass it the jsonData string) it works fine????

Comment: If you think the my answer helped you can you upvote and accept it? Basically it motivates :-)

Answer (score -1):

Solved it with an update to my c# webservice method.

JSON that is passed in looks like the following:

```
'{"data":{"jsonData":[{"id":"1","name":"Alan","url":"http://www.google.com"},{"id":"2","name":"Louis","url":"http://www.yahoo.com"}]}}'
```

and the c# webservice method looks like the following:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string myUpdate(object data)
        {
            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                xd = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "jsonData");
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xd));
                return "success"; //return ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString(); //just to test
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "ERROR: " + e + "!";
            }
        }
```

Comment: It will be better if you could tell what exactly you did to solve the problem than let the user go through and understand it.